# Measuring User Login Time of a User in an Active Directory Environment from an End User Perspective

Tags: active-directory, login

I want to measure the time taken by the users to login to the Active Directory Server, note that this time should also include the time taken for the logon scripts to run fully.

After lots of Googling I was repeatedly told to add performance counters but that wouldn't be much of a end user perspective.

So I really wanted to know if there are any ways (through VBscript/Powershell for example) I could simulate a login.

Note: Initially I thought of authenticating using a program (C#), but that wouldn't include the loading of the logon Script.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows 2000, Windows XP, or Windows Server 2003 you can enable user environment debug logging:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221833

If you're running Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows Server 2008 you can look in the Group Policy event log:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/03/11/group-policy-logging-on-windows-vista.aspx